# PayPal Webhooks: Are Invoice, Payment sale, authorization and capture Webhooks needed if I only use Billing agreements

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-webhooks

The business model which I need to cover is to sell subscriptions only. I don't need to sell individual products. My question is: do I need to implement and support listening to Invoicing, Payment sale, authorization and capture webhooks, or I can just implement Billing plan and subscription webhooks?

Invoice and Payment webhooks which I'm referring to:

```
Payment authorization created
Payment authorization voided
Payment capture completed
Payment capture denied
Payment capture pending
Payment capture refunded
Payment capture reversed
Payment sale completed
Payment sale denied
Payment sale pending
Payment sale refunded
Payment sale reversed
Invoicing invoice cancelled
Invoicing invoice paid
Invoicing invoice refunded
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not processing any payments in your model and you are interested only in subscriptions, you can implement subscription Webhooks alone. But if you process any payments, we recommend you to implement and listen to payment related Webhooks as well so you get notified.

Thanks!